# How to activate deflection?

Tags: particles

I have a flow a sand falling on a plane created in Particles but I can't get it to deflect from the inclined plane under the flow. It keeps going through the plane. Supposedly there is a button for deflection but I can't find it. How can make the plane deflect the flow of sand?
Blender file attached.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2706" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2706/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. RMD the plane in Object Mode. Go to Physics and then to Collision, then give Stickiness a high value, like 5. Now the flow of sand slides from the plane before continue falling by the side.